# How to get related data with many-to-many relationship?

Tags: many-to-many, ef-core-2.2

I have models Project and Programmer with many-to-many relationship:

```
public class Project
{
    public Project()
    {
        ProjectProgrammers = new HashSet<ProjectProgrammer>();
    }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProjectProgrammer> ProjectProgrammers { get; set; }
}

public class Programmer
{
    public Programmer()
    {
        ProjectProgrammers = new HashSet<ProjectProgrammer>();
    }

    public int ProgrammerID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProjectProgrammer> ProjectProgrammers { get; set; }
}
```

There is model ProjectProgrammer:

```
public class ProjectProgrammer
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

    public int ProgrammerID { get; set; }
    public virtual Programmer Programmer { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectProgrammer>()
            .HasKey(pp => new { pp.ProjectID, pp.ProgrammerID });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectProgrammer>()
            .HasOne(pp => pp.Project)
            .WithMany(p => p.ProjectProgrammers)
            .HasForeignKey(pp => pp.ProjectID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectProgrammer>()
            .HasOne(pp => pp.Programmer)
            .WithMany(p => p.ProjectProgrammers)
            .HasForeignKey(pp => pp.ProgrammerID);
```

When I'm trying to load related data with Include() and Theninclude():

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Project>> ListAsync()
    {
        return await _context.Projects.Include(p => p.ProjectProgrammers)
                                      .ThenInclude(pp => pp.Programmer)
                                      .ToListAsync();
    }
```

I get only first record with incomplete programmer info:

```
[{"projectID":100,"name":"Project1","description":"Desc","projectProgrammers":[{"projectID":100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding [JsonIgnore] attribute to one of navigations property. More information: http://ericsmasal.com/2018/01/04/ef-core-and-defeating-the-self-referencing-loop/